# Workflow and Associated Task Form Names

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, tasks

I have question regarding the InfoPath Forms that autogenerated by the Workflow Tasks. I was wondering if it is possible to give these forms more meaingful names.

The current problem example: If I create a custom task process called "BTP Review", the InfoPath form that will generate for it will be name "Task_x0028_6_x0029.xsn", instead of a descriptive name like the iniation form is.

Have others had this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I did not get a chance to to it, you can try following:

1. Open site in SPD. Close the workflow designer (if it is open)
2. Go to All Files - Workflows - Click on Name of your workflow (if you don't see all files, it might be SPD permission and configuration issue)

[image]

3. SPD will show all the files that the workflow consists of including rules and infopath forms
4. Rename the XSN files
5. Those XSN files would have been referred in at least *.wfconfig.xml file. Open the XML file(s) which refer them and rename them

Save everything and try opening the workflow again.

Comment: Ashish, If its the forms that display in the lower right hand corner of the Workflow Main Page, I am not given the option to rename these.

Comment: it would not allow there. close that page. then look in the left navigation pane. You will see All Files - usually the last option. let me if you dont find it.

Comment: Still can't see all files. This SPD 2010.

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks Ashish, they must have some permissions locked on me. I do not have all of those options available.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Ashish Patel's answer, if you were to just do those changes alone, then exported the workflow, it would not work. To get this to work

1. Save workflow as template then download file from site assets
2. Change file extension *.wsp -> *.cab. Extract using iZarc
3. inside the Instances folder, change any reference to the old file name in Elements.xml and Feature.xml
4. Inside Files/workflows/%WORKFLOW_NAME% change file extension *.xsn -> *.cab. Extract using iZarc
5. Change any reference to the old name in manifest file
6. Using iZarc, recreate the cab files with the new file names. (*Note: Don't highlight the files you want and then archive it, start with iZarc, create a new file, then select the files. Doing it the other way will add a folder to the structure)

Good luck, took me a freaking long time to figure this out...